# ViewController added programmatically looks shifted/transalted (iOS, swift, storyboards)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm learning about View Controller Containers and nesting Viev Controllers in iOS, using swift and storyboard.
The problem is - added view is not within the bounds of a parent view.
This is how it looks in interface builder:
[image: Screens]
The left view is parent view controller, and the white area is view, in which I want to place blue view controller.
I imagine, that the blue view controller should fill this white view.
However, this is how it looks on iPad:
[image]

It looks, like the blue view is placed the same amount pixels below the top of white view, as is the white view to the top of the screen.

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var vcContainer: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController")
    displayVC(vc!)

}

func displayVC(content: UIViewController) {
    content.view.frame = self.vcContainer.frame
    content.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.vcContainer.addSubview(content.view)

    self.addChildViewController(content)

    content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you haven't added constraints or configured autoresizing mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `self.vcContainer.addSubview(content.view)`

it should be `self.view.addSubview(content.view)`

Because when you set frame for your child viewcontroller like this:

`content.view.frame = self.vcContainer.frame`

it is relative to parent viewcontroller, not `vcContainer`, hence after you added `content` into `vcContainer`, it's in wrong position.

If you want to add `content` into `vcContainer`, you should choose another way to place `content.view`, something like pin edges of `content` to edges of `vcContainer` using `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Full working code:

```
UIViewController *vc =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];

[self addChildViewController:vc];

vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.container addSubview:vc.view];
[self.container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:vc.view
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                              toItem:self.container
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                          multiplier:1.0
                                            constant:0]];
[self.container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:vc.view
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                              toItem:self.container
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                          multiplier:1.0
                                            constant:0]];
[self.container
    addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintWithItem:vc.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.container
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                              multiplier:1.0
                                constant:0]];
[self.container
    addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintWithItem:vc.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.container
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                              multiplier:1.0
                                constant:0]];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Adding constraints will be a lot easier if you use [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout).

Comment: That works great. Could you also tell me, what's the equivalent of this code in PureLayout?

Comment: With PureLayout, after added `vc.view` to `container`, you can just `[vc.view autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges]`. Yes, it is really that easy.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints set in your StoryBoard on your view specify an exact distance to be kept from the top.

This distance is true for some devices, so it might looks like it is in the middle, but on the ipad this is not the case.

You should add a height on your view, and than position vertically and horizontally to the center of your superview.